# How can i view a local laptop website on my iPhone

Tags: apache, mobile

On my Macbook Pro I've set up the Apache Webserver. I can view these sites via localhost in the browser address bar.

isn't there a way i can view these websites on my iPhone?

isn't there an IP address i can type into the browser address bar on my iPHone?

this would speed up dev time tremendously!

anyone? ....know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If your iphone and Mac use the same network, you can type your laptop local IP address in your iphone, it would be like `192.168.1.2`, it's different from your external IP address.

Comment: thanks but could you be more explicit? for example if ip address is 11.222.333.44 and my local website, which is normally http://mywebsite.local:8083, then what would the url be using the ip address? i've tried to combine the above url's but nothing is working